# Invoking multiple instances of the same jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, code-reuse, reusability

I have a `jQuery UI` dialog with several tabs, sometimes, I need to pop up one of those tabs as a  separate dialog (atop of tabbed initial dialog), so, can I achieve this by re-using the same dialog?

(of course with a bit run-time customizations, `JavaScript`/`DOM HTML` manipulations, but with the same `<div></div>` template initially defined and with the same `HTML FORM` elements IDs)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the optimal solution, but could be an approach of what should you do.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <div class="dtabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab1">First</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Second</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Third</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab1">
            <p>First!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2">
            <p>Second!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3">
            <p>Third!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input value="Tab 1 on Dialog" type="button" alt="1" />
<input value="Tab 2 on Dialog" type="button" alt="2" />
<input value="Tab 3 on Dialog" type="button" alt="3" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    // Dialog without autoOpen just to hide it from viewport
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $('input').click(function () {
        // Clone the dialog and append it to body
        // Get "tab" number to know which tab should I set as active later
        var d = $('#dialog').clone().appendTo('body'),
            tab = $(this).attr('alt')-1;
        // Assign "dialog" behaviour and remove it when I close it
        d.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            close: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
            }
        });
        // Tabs inside my dialog has "tabs" behaviour by JQueryUI
        d.find('.dtabs').tabs({
            active: tab
        });
        // Open up!
        d.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/franverona/k7cuH/

Let me explain you what I did:

1. I create my dialog in pure HTML and using JQueryUI assign it a `dialog` behaviour.
2. Every button has a property that will tell me later what tab should I open in my future dialog.
3. When user click on button I clone my previous dialog, append it to body and get "tab" attribute. Then I assign it a `dialog` behaviour without autoOpen and with a function associated to `close` event to remove it from DOM (to avoid multiple dialogs on my HTML body).
4. Before open, I assign a `tabs` behaviour to all the content inside my recently created dialog (look that I'm using `find` function) and set as an active tab the correct tab using `tab` property retrieved before.
5. Now I'm ready to open my dialog with all set up.

I repeat: this isn't an optimal solution, but should work as a prototype of later development iterations.

Happy coding!